# car and insurance when buying a used car : For first Car?

Tags: buying

When buying your very first car  : After buying a used car from a dealer/private owner then drive home , what insurance should I have ? and also when doing a test drive how insurance work ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about insurance and buying a car

Comment: If there's a better *exchange, then move it there, but I think this type of question adds value to the site.

Comment: @JuannStrauss I disagree, the help section states `Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and their accessories, internal combustion engines, even in applications other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or engine accessories.` [See here for more info.](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope)

Comment: Well you're welcome to disagree, but you are disagreeing with something I DIDN'T say. What I said was that this question adds value, NOT that it is a 100% fit for maintenance and repair.

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on the country you're in, but usually, if you are financing the car through a financial institution, you'll have to offer to purchase a car then immediately apply for insurance. You'll only be allowed to take possession of the car once you have insurance. This usually takes only a few hours.

I don't think this applies when you buy the car cash. But in some countries, like England, you MUST be insured, no matter what.

As far as test drives go, the dealer is supposed to have insurance that covers any accidents you may get into, but may require you to pay an "excess" amount. However, you're only liable to pay it IF you were told about it beforehand and they can prove that you agreed to it.

Comment: Hi , yes it's England. So basically  I just want to understand the process from test drive to when drive home after buying the car. Specially when you buy from dealers and private owners can be found in gumtree and autotrader . And no financing. In this case how can I get insured ? is there any daily insurance something like that?

Comment: Sorry, that was everything I know about how it works in England. And I got that from Top Gear. It's probably best to ask the dealer himself if you trust him enough.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, you must have at least third party insurance to cover you to drive the car. You have several different possible situations here though.

1. Test driving a car from a dealer - in this situation, as Juann says, the dealer should provide the insurance.
2. Test driving a car from a private seller - here you are responsible. If you already have a car with a fully comprehensive policy, it may cover you to drive other cars that are not owned by you (check your policy details). If not, you can buy "day insurance" from a number of sites online, for between £10 and £20 (it may have gone up since I last looked...) per day.
3. After you have bought the car - At this point, it is yours, so the trick in 2 doesn't apply. Again you can get day insurance, or phone your existing insurer and change your policy over to the new car - some insurers may allow you to add a second car to an existing policy temporarily, but most won't.
4. After you have bought the car, if you don't have another car already - This is the easy one. between paying the deposit and collecting the car, take out a new policy...

Comment: So after buying the car I must take day insurance to take it home ?

Comment: :) sorry I found the answer" between paying the deposit and collecting the car, take out a new policy..."

Answer (score 1):

In the UK and the USA, you must have valid insurance to take the car on the road no matter what. No insurance - no driving on the road.

If you already have a car you are insured to drive, and you are the policy holder, your policy may allow you to drive other cars. Any other car you do drive must also have insurance on it. The cover will be *pro-rata* between the insurance companies, usually at third party only. This does not apply to named drivers, a named driver cannot drive another vehicle pro-rata.

A dealer should have a motor traders policy which will allow customers to test drive vehicles.

Short term insurance cover is available. It may also be available as an extension from your present insurers.